# RegularExpressionValidator in codebehind (web services)

Tags: asp.net, regex, web-services

i am working with web services webmethod and i have a method that accepts a string of `phonumber (1234567890)` and how can i make sure before i make a call to API that, the phone number is valid (no characters or not less then 10 digits)

how can i implement in web.service?

Answer (score 1):

You would implement the RegularExpressionValidator on the UI.  If the text doesn't meet the regular expression pattern, the validator IsValid will be False.  The page shouldn't execute  any code until the phone number field meets your regular expression pattern.

Before calling your web service, check if Page.IsValid, too.

Comment: thats true what you have said but my situation is that i will be providing services and i dont really sure if the user will valid before they call the servcies with valid or invalid phone number so just wanted to double check before i execute any call

Comment: The RegularExpressionValidator on the page will STOP any kind of post back from occuring if it is in an IsValid = false state.

Comment: looks like you still did not get.. .i am not calling web servcie i am providing services to the other users.

Comment: And you don't "get" that this type of check needs to be implemented on the UI side.  The application makes a call to the web services you provide.  You cannot stop a call to your web service from occuring.  You can, implement a regex to check the incoming string as Tim has indicated above.

Comment: well.. i want to implement on web services and i can just rely on UI side and throw an appropriate error if the user dont provide correct phone number.

Answer (score 0):

To validate a string that consists only of digits and is at least 10 digits long, use this (server- or client-side):

```
^\d{10,}$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^        # Anchor the regex at the start of the string.
\d{10,}  # Match 10 or more digits until the...
$        # end of the string.
```

Comment: i want to allow only NUMBERS (no space or nothing) just valid 10 digit number.

Comment: Ah, OK, the parentheses in your example had thrown me off course :)

Comment: how would you implement in codebehind, do you have a sample code?